# Skipping a field on save (Django models, Insert and Update)

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, orm

Given PostgreSQL 9.2.10, Django 1.8, python 2.7.5, the following model:

```
class soapProdAPI(models.Model):
    soap_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    soap_host = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='0.0.0.0')
    soap_asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

And the following code:

```
tableProdSoap = soapProdQuery()


@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=2))
def saveSoapProd():
    tableProdSoap = soapProdQuery()
    if tableProdSoap != None:
        for item in tableProdSoap:
            commit = soapProdAPI(soap_id=item[0], soap_host=item[1], soap_asset=item[2], soap_state=item[3])
            commit.save()
    saveSoapNullIP()
```

To answer Josué Padilla's question:

```
@task
def saveSoapNullIP():
    missingIP = soapProdAPI.objects.filter(soap_ip='0.0.0.0')
    if missingIP:
        for record in missingIP:
            if str(record.soap_host).lower().startswith('1a'):
                fqdn = str(record.soap_host) + 'stringvaluehere'
            elif str(record.soap_host).lower().startswith('1b'):
                fqdn = str(record.soap_host) + 'stringvaluehere'
            elif str(record.soap_host).lower().startswith('1c'):
                fqdn = str(record.soap_host) + 'stringvaluehere'
            else:
                fqdn = str(record.soap_host) + 'stringvaluehere'
            try:
                hostIp = check_output('host %s' % fqdn, shell=True)
                hostIp = hostIp.split()[-1]
            except:
                hostIp = '0.0.0.0'
            record.soap_ip = hostIp
            record.save(update_fields=['soap_ip'])
```

My soapProdQuery only returns these 4 fields where there is a 5th field in the model (`soap_ip`). I know it is probably not the *best* way to do it but I have a separate block of code that queries the db for `None` values in `soap_ip` runs a subprocess host on them and saves it back with the ip address (The number of rows returned/updated should get smaller each pass through, as opposed to putting the logic for doing a host lookup into the request/this celery task itself which would run every API request. I have tried this already, it takes FOREVER to return the completed data.). The soap API I query does not provide the IP or I would grab it that way obviously. This all runs as background tasks using celery to make it invisible/seamless to the web user.

The issue I run into is that every time the `saveSoapProd()` runs it overwrites the previous `soap_ip` field with `'0.0.0.0'` thus negating the work of my other function. The other issue is that I cannot `force_insert` or `force_update` as I need both functionalities with this. My question is this: is there a way to selectively update/insert at the same time and completely exclude doing anything to the `soap_ip` each time `saveSoapProd()` runs? Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

** **EDIT 1** **

I may or may not have found a solution in [update_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#update-or-create) or [get_or_create](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create), however I am unsure on the exact usage. The docs have me slightly confused.

** **EDIT 2** **

I guess get_or_create is a bust. Works first pass through but every save after that fails with this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<console>", line 8, in saveSoapProd
  File "/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 690, in save
    % ', '.join(non_model_fields))
ValueError: The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: soap_id
```

Here is the code:

```
@periodic_task(run_every=timedelta(minutes=2))
def saveSoapProd():
    tableProdSoap = soapProdQuery()
    if tableProdSoap != None:
        for item in tableProdSoap:
            obj, created = soapProdAPI.objects.get_or_create(soap_id=item[0], defaults={'soap_host': item[1], 'soap_asset': item[2], 'soap_state': item[3]})
            if created == False:
                commit = soapProdAPI(soap_id=item[0], soap_host=item[1], soap_asset=item[2], soap_state=item[3])
                commit.save(update_fields=['soap_id', 'soap_host', 'soap_asset', 'soap_state'])
```

I will be honest, I am not entirely sure what is causing this error.

---

** **EDIT 3/CURRENT SOLUTION** **

I was able to resolve my own issue by modifying my model and my task function. The solution uses get_or_create, but you could easily extrapolate how to use update_or_create from the solution provided. See the selected answer below for a coded example.

---

** **TLDR** **

I want to do a .save() where it may need to do a insert for new records or update for changed records **WITHOUT** touching the `soap_ip` field (no `insert_only` or `update_only`).

Comment: What does saveSoapNullIP() do?  It is executed every time that the function runs. Is this ok?

Comment: @JosuéPadilla I added in saveSoapNullIP() for your review. It's probably not the best way to do things but it is better than putting it directly in the task itself or in the api call. This at least makes it so that the amount of records I have to update should reduce each pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own issue without modifying the save method by making the following changes to my model:

```
class soapProdAPI(models.Model):
    soap_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(unique=True, null=False)
    soap_host = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='0.0.0.0')
    soap_asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

and my task:

```
def saveSoapProd():
    tableProdSoap = soapProdQuery()
    if tableProdSoap != None:
        for item in tableProdSoap:
            try:
                obj, created = soapProdAPI.objects.get_or_create(soap_id=item[0], defaults={'soap_host': item[1], 'soap_asset': item[2], 'soap_state': item[3]})
                if created == False:
                    obj.soap_host  = item[1]
                    obj.soap_asset = item[2]
                    obj.soap_state = item[3]
                    obj.save(update_fields=['soap_host', 'soap_asset', 'soap_state'])
            except:
                continue
    saveSoapMissingIP()
```

**EDIT**

Just noticed Josué Padilla's response, which was in fact part of my problem that I solved with this answer. Thank you to Josué for all of your help.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you already knew this, but you can override the save() function of your model.

```
class soapProdAPI(models.Model):
    soap_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    soap_host = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_ip = models.GenericIPAddressField(default='0.0.0.0')
    soap_asset = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    soap_state = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    # Override save
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.soap_ip != '0.0.0.0':
          self.soap_ip = your_ip # Here you can  get your old IP an save that instead of 0.0.0.0
```

**EDIT**

You are getting

`ValueError: The following fields do not exist in this model or are m2m fields: soap_id`

Because you are trying to update `soap_id`, that field is defined as your model's primary key, so it is immutable when updating. That's why it crashes when you do:

`commit.save(update_fields=['soap_id', 'soap_host', 'soap_asset', 'soap_state'])`

Try removing `soap_id` from `update_fields`.

Comment: I knew of it and have considered it for my options, but I figured there was a convenience method or possible another way to do this without redefining model methods. Thanks for the suggestion though.